# Select hidden element to upload file with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I feel like i'm pretty close but i'm struggling on this, I have a button that i click which will open the OS file window, but the element to send the file to is hidden and i'm not sure how to unhide it. Most of what i've researched is a few years old at this point and methods are deprecated.

Here's the snippet of the html code.

```html
<p-fileupload _ngcontent-ims-c84="" mode="basic" maxfilesize="40000000" chooselabel="Upload" class="p-element" style="float: right;">
<!---->
<div class="p-fileupload p-fileupload-basic p-component ng-star-inserted">
    <p-messages class="p-element ng-tns-c81-29 ng-star-inserted">
        <div role="alert" class="p-messages p-component ng-tns-c81-29">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
        </div>
    </p-messages>
        <span tabindex="0" pripple="" class="p-ripple p-element p-button p-component p-fileupload-choose">
            <span class="p-button-icon p-button-icon-left pi pi-plus">
            </span>
            <span class="p-button-label">Upload</span>
            <input type="file" accept="undefined" class="ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->
        </span>
    </div>
    <!---->
</p-fileupload>
```

Here's my code, values_g is a file name copied from a cell.

```py
driver.find_Element(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"file\"]")).sendkeys(values_g)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, I ended up using pyautogui to write values to the OS file window.
The issue I had was it would type too quickly and cut off a few leading characters, I slowed down the type interval (not the issue) and added a 1 second sleep before typing (fixed the issue)

```
import pyautogui

time.sleep(1) #leave this other pyautogui cuts off leading characters

pyautogui.write("write something", interval=0.02) # interval slows type speed
pyautogui.press('enter')
```